# PHP IF Statement - Sectioning off multiple conditions

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

It seems inefficient to me to write multiple conditions to do the same action,,, for example

```
if ( (condition_one || (condition_two && condition_three) )
{
    // Do this ...
}
elseif ( condition_two && condition_three)
{
    // Do same as before ...
}
else
{
    // Do that ...
}
```

Would there be a valid approach to accomplishing this? Where condition_two and condition_three have to be executed together but separately from condition_one...

```
if ( (condition_one || (condition_two && condition_three) )
{
    // Do this ...
}
else
{
    // Do that ...
}
```

In other words,,, is there some way, that I am unaware of, to do this:

```
if ( ( $a < $b || ( $a <= $b && $c = $d ) )
{
    echo 'foo';
}
else
{
    echo 'bar';
}
```

Rather than this:

```
if ( ( $a < $b )
{
    echo 'foo';
}
elseif ( $a <= $b && $c = $d )
{
    echo 'foo';
}
else
{
    echo 'bar';
}
```

Comment: there an extra ( on your example if ( >(< $a < $b || ( $a <= $b && $c = $d ) )

it should work as it is.

Comment: I see the same as @DaniloKobold

Comment: hm.. I suppose I might have nested things wrong.. I thought i was losing my mind and wasn't getting something about conditions,,,

Comment: do you know anything about switch fallback?

Comment: Yes I do.. I It's an overkill for what I need. Danilo is right. I made a mistake nesting things and i was getting weird results.. I got it right now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test this easy but you had an extra paren

```
<?php

function testNest($a, $b, $c, $d){
    if ($a < $b || ( $a <= $b && $c = $d )) {
        echo 'foo';
    } else {
        echo 'bar';
    }
}


testNest(3, 2, 3, 2); //bar
testNest(1, 2, 3, 2); //foo

function testElif($a, $b, $c, $d){
    if ($a < $b ){
        echo 'foo';
    } elseif ( $a <= $b && $c = $d ) {
        echo 'foo';
    } else {
        echo 'bar';
    }
}

testElif(3, 2, 3, 2); //bar
testElif(1, 2, 3, 2); //foo
```

I'll let you come up with more examples but there really is no need for elseif

Comment: Oh this is very useful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra ( in your code above but another way you could do this is ti use what we call switch fallback: something like so:

```
switch(true){
case $a < $b: //fallback
case ( $a <= $b && $c = $d ):
   //do something
   break;

default:
  //default action
break;

}
```

Notice i skipped a 'break' for the fallback, so it will run if any of the 2 'Cases' is (true).